# On which disk is a file located in a btrfs RAID-1 array/filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

I have a btrfs array with 5 disks in RAID-1 mounted on `/mnt/array`:

```
# btrfs filesystem show /mnt/array
Label: 'nicefilesystem'  uuid: censored
        Total devices 5 FS bytes used 4.95TiB
        devid    1 size 2.11TiB used 2.03TiB path /dev/sda
        devid    2 size 3.11TiB used 3.04TiB path /dev/sdg
        devid    3 size 2.11TiB used 1.92TiB path /dev/sdd
        devid    4 size 1.11TiB used 1.02TiB path /dev/sdc
        devid    5 size 2.11TiB used 2.03TiB path /dev/sdh
```

I have the file `/mnt/array/NiceFile`. How do I find out on which disks is located?

Comment: It will rather be a list of hard disks. The file will likely be spread across many devices.

Comment: Yes, this is is a possibility. Let's say 2 drives fail. This is not "covered" by the RAID-1 setup. Hence, having the possibility to check if specific files are located in these 2 failed devices will enable me check if there are permanently damaged files.

Comment: I really doubt if such too exists. If I were you, I'd ask the question directly to the btrfs-kernel mailing list. And if you do please - post their reply here. It would be easier to find.

Comment: I did ask there. They said it wasn't possible, so I thought of asking it here. :) Many thanks.